# padding-top stretches div in chrome

Tags: css, padding

I have code like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/y09dngnj/1/

```
<div style="border: 1px solid green">
    <div class="biddingStat" id="biddingStat0" 
        style="background-color: #DC0707;opacity: 1;
        text-align: center; ">10000
    </div>
</div>

.biddingStat {
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #eeee22;
  padding-top: 20px;
    /*left: 40px;*/
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If you change css from `padding-top: 20px` to `padding-top: 5px` and rerun fiddle, although there is height 100px of red div, the height changes. I'd expect that text would change its position to be more distant from top edge but height of div would stay 100px no matter what. 
How to keep 100px height of div and have text padded from top?

Comment: This is because of box sizing (https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: and that was the remedy for me. thank you very much!

Comment: @Kalreg No, that was a hack! If you started out with that model, you get one result but you didn't. All you did was make it work. You didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `padding-top` to `margin-top` in the CSS file.

See: [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid green"><div class="biddingStat" id="biddingStat0" style="background-color: #DC0707;opacity: 1;text-align: center; ">10000</div></div>

<style>
  .biddingStat
  {
 width: 80px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0px;
 background-color: #eeee22;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding-top: 20px;
 /*left: 40px;*/
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 min-height: 30px;
 height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: it is bad idea because text isnt padded anymore

Comment: Okay, then you can add `margin-top` in addition to `padding-top`.

Comment: if i do that red box hasnt height 100px anymore - it is larger

Comment: @Kal I am not having that problem. Simply add the margin to what you have. I will edit my post to show this. It is the red box you are talking about, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want padding to affect the dimensions of an element you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` which will allow the div to not be affected by any padding or borders added to it.